# Add, Delete & Clear HTML Elements in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the requirement scenario, i am to `add, delete` `textboxes & select dropdown` on a `button click`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/842ur4zw/)

My `Add` functionality works well. How to `Delete & Clear Rows`.

For `Delete` the last Row should get deleted & when `new Row` is added after deletion the `id` hierarchy should continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable').find("tr:last-child").remove();
});

$("#btnClear").click(function () {
$('#filterTable').html("")  ;  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/842ur4zw/3/

Answer (score 1):

`find('tr:last-child')` will find last row added and `remove()` will remove it. using `find('input')` u can find all input, and just assign emty string to it.

```
 $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable').find('tr:last-child').remove();
 });

 $("#btnClear").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable').find('input').val('');
 });
```

or if by `clear all` u mean remove all controlls not clearing values in it use `empty()` like below.

```
$("#btnClear").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable').empty();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this .. empty() and remove functions

```
 $("#btnDelete").click(function () {

     $('#filterTable').find("tr:last-child").remove();


 });

 $("#btnClear").click(function () {
     var id = $('table tr').size();
     $("#filterTable").empty();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/842ur4zw/2/)

```
// to delete the first child which was added

$("#btnDelete").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable tr:first').remove()
});

// to clear the values of input field

$("#btnClear").click(function () {
    $('#filterTable input').val(" ")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('tab_Id');
var tableRows = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var rowCount = tableRows.length;

for (var i=rowCount-1; i>0; i--) {
   myTable.removeChild(tableRows[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By clear all you meant, only clear inputs.

I guess this would help.

```
<form>
    <table id="filterTable"></table>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" />
    <!-- previous
    <input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Clear All" />
    -->
    <input type="reset" id="btnClear" value="Clear All" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/842ur4zw/4/